# how to get only the type of Enumerable?

Tags: c#, ienumerable

I want to separate `IEnumerable` variables by their types. My code is like this:

```
if (type is IEnumerable)
{
    var listGenericType = type.GetType().GetGenericTypeDefinition().Name;
    listGenericType = listGenericType.Substring(0, listGenericType.IndexOf('`'));
    if (listGenericType == "List") {
        //do something
    }

    else if (listGenericType == "HashSet") {
        //do something
    }
}
```

When I use `type.GetType().GetGenericTypeDefinition().Name`, the `listGenericType` is like `` List`1 `` or `` HashSet`1 `` but I want it like `List` or `HashSet`. Thus, I used `Substring` to handle this issue!

Is there anyway to handle this problem without postProcessing `string` type? I mean something like below code:

```
if (type is IEnumerable)
{
    var listGenericType = type.GetType().GetGenericTypeDefinitionWithoutAnyNeedForPostProcessing();
    if (listGenericType == "List") {
        //do something
    }

    else if (listGenericType == "HashSet") {
        //do something
    }
}
```

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getgenerictypedefinition.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have to compare it against a string. Since `GetGenericTypeDefinition()` returns a **type**, all you have to do is compare it against a type using the `typeof` operator, as such:

```
if (type is IEnumerable)
{
    var listGenericType = type.GetType().GetGenericTypeDefinition();

    if (listGenericType == typeof(List<>)) {
        //do something
    }
    else if (listGenericType == typeof(HashShet<>)) {
        //do something
    }
 }
```

As @nopeflow kindly pointed out below, if your type if not a generic type then `GetGenericTypeDefinition()` will throw an `InvalidOperationException`. Make sure you account for that.

Comment: It's wroth to mention that some type may implement `IEnumerable` but that type is not generic one. (The type may Implement `IEnumerable` but not `IEnumerable<SomeType>`.... Then, `GetGenericTypeDefinition` will throw `InvalidOperationException`.)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are looking for Generic types only, I believe this might help you out.

```
            List<int> someObject = new List<int>();
            Type currentType = someObject.GetType();

            if (currentType.IsGenericType)
            {
                if (currentType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(List<>))
                {
                    // Do something
                }
                else if (currentType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(HashSet<>))
                {
                    // Do something else
                }
            }
```